# $.isEmptyObject not working in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble creating an if statement with $.isEmptyObject.

```
function x (response) {
    if(!$.isEmptyObject(response)){

    var livsmedel = response.livsmedel;

        livsmedel.forEach(function (produkt) {
        // code continues
        });
   }

   else {
        $("tbody").empty();
   }
 }
```

The code works mostly fine but the last `else` doesn't work. So the table doesn't go away. The `else` doesn't work at all, not even when I try to alert something.

So I guess the problem is somewhere in `if(!$.isEmptyObject(response))`. Console doesn't show any errors/warnings though. Does someone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: `console.log(response)` for no search results and see if its really empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because response is not empty: `{"livsmedel":[], "responseStatus": 200}`

Do a check for `response.livsmedel`:

```
if (response.livsmedel && response.livsmedel.length > 0) {
// do something
}
```